# How to customize access to spring endpoint with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application expose endpoints like spring actuator endpoints and i should secure the acces to some endpoints with a customise logic.

i have this code:

```
   fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain? {
        val letRecoAuthenticationFilter = LetRecoAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, authenticationContextService)
        letRecoAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(LetRecoAuthenticationFailureHandler())
        letRecoAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler())
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(letRecoAuthenticationFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
                .authorizeHttpRequests { authorizeRequests ->
                    authorizeRequests
                            
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger*")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/login/form")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/login/connection")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/feature-toggles")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/feature-toggles*")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/example*")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/cache/list")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/cache/configuration")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/cache/*")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/actuator/*")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/*")).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/actuator/loggers/*")).access(AuthorizationManagers.allOf(hasRight()))
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                }
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable()
        return http.build()
    }
```

i like that the access to /actuator/loggers/* should be allowed when my method hasRight() return true

```
  private fun hasRight(): Boolean {
        // Implement your logic to call the service.hasright method
        return service.hasRight()
    }
```

how can i do this with spring boot and spring security?
thank's!

Comment: what about roles ?  something like this `requestMatchers("/actuator/loggers/*").hasRole("ROLE");`

Comment: I don't use roles here, just a method that should return true or false

Comment: ok, just have a look to [Referring to Beans in Web Security Expressions module](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html) it is exactly what you need `WebExpressionAuthorizationManager`